# LM2596 Issue (Burns out)

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm using LM2596 for the power supply of SIM800 GSM module.
LM2596 is stepping down voltage to 3.8V. I have attached schematic diagram of it.

It is working good if I use 12V-5A SMPS as power source. But when I use other supply like 24V-2A, LM2596 burns out while SIM800 is registering on network(during this time SIM800 draws more current). I'm not getting why it is burning out.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Circuit diagram from questtion: -

[image]

You have your flyback diode in the wrong place. D1 on your circuit should be where D1 is shown below: -

[image]

I'm not ruling out other problems as well.